# Returning an EditorTemplate as a Partial View from a Controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I would like to return an EditorTemplate from my controller as a Partial View.

I am currently doing:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix="Create")]CreateViewModel model)
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Template.cshtml", model);
}
```

The problem is that after I do this the `Create_` prefix goes away from my view. Is there a way to return an editor template as a partial view and retain the prefix?

Index.cshtml
    @model IndexViewModel

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Create, "Template")

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

I am submitting this form with an AJAX call. When I originally call EditorFor, all of the fields have a prefix of `Create_`. However, after I submit the form and return this PartialView, the prefix is lost.

Comment: Why don't you just use EditorFor?

Comment: I am initially. I am posting my form with an AJAX call, when the form is invalid I need to return it as a partial view and replace the contents

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since the template wasn't invoked in the context of the main view it loses its context. You could define the prefix in this case as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix="Create")]CreateViewModel model)
{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Create";
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Template.cshtml", model);
}
```

Comment: Can't you do that in the controller too?

Comment: @SLaks, yes, you can and it is an excellent idea and far better solution than doing it in the template. Will update my post. Thanks.

Comment: Ha I was just about to post the answer myself after finding this. You can do it in the controller too actually.

Comment: I might create some utility method that will inspect a model looking for a Bind attribute, if it finds one that has a Prefix, it will set the prefix to that value.

Comment: Darin, I love your answers. Every time I have problem I can find best answer here, your answer. Thank you a lot)